# Variance of chain length in hashtable

Tags: probability-theory, hash, hash-tables

I have a hashtable with length $m$. Initially it's empty. Next, $n/2$ unique random numbers $\in [0, n]$ are added to it.

What would be variance of chain length when such $n/2$ numbers are being added $x$ times?

I tested it using code with $n=2^{16}$, $m=2^{15}$ (part of md5 was used as index) and got the following results:

$$
\begin{array}{|l|r|r|r|r|} \hline
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\text{Variance} & 2 & 6 & 12 & 20 \\\hline
\text{Mean} & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

How can I calculate these values without testing, or what is the probability of a value being added into a specific index in the table?

Hash table looks like following:

[image]

### Second variant

Given table with size of $m$ (let it be $table_1,\ldots,table_m$). Initially it filled with $0$.

Next, I am inserting values into it: I choose $n/2$ different random numbers ($a_1,\ldots,a_{n/2}$) between $0$ and $n$ .
For each of the chosen numbers I am calculating hash (using SHA) $h_i$ with size of $m$:
$$
h_1=hash(a_1),...,h_{n/2}=hash(a_{n/2})
$$
Calculated hash is the index for the table. For each calculated index I am increasing value in the table by $1$.
$$
table_{h_1}=table_{h_1}+1,...,table_{h_{n/2}}=table_{h_{n/2}}+1
$$
What would be variance of the values in the table ($table_1,\ldots,table_m$) if I do that insertion $x$ times?

In the example result I am calculated variance like this:

$u_1,...,u_k$ - unique values from the table ($table_1,\ldots,table_m$)

$p_1,...,p_k$ - probability of appearance of the corresponding unique number $u$ in the table

$Var = \sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i(u_i-mean)^2$

Comment: What do you mean by "$n/2$ unique random numbers"? What is the significant of $[0,n]$, and what do you mean by this notation? What do you mean by chain length? There are many implementations of hash tables. Do you know how to calculate the mean?

Comment: In short, a lot of details are missing. Don't forget that we can't read your mind and can't see your program. (And no, we don't want to see it.)

Comment: From your data, I guess that the mean is $2x$ and that the variance is $x^2+x$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, I meant that for example if $n=2^{16}$ then $2^{15}$ numbers being added to table. All these $2^{15}$ numbers are randomly chosen between 0 and $2^{16}$ and all of them are different. In my case if hash table already have number by index then it being added to the list under same index. So I want to know how to exactly calculate variance of the length of these lists. I though that it would have Binomial distribution with probability of $1/m$ and trials count $(n*x)/2$, but variance is different, I think because of collisions

Comment: By experimenting with parameters I found that variance would be something like $\frac{2^{n-1} x (x+1)}{2^{m+1}}$, but I still don`t know is it correct or not

Comment: Can you explain your model, and how to calculate the mean? I have no idea at the moment what you're trying to calculate, and that makes it impossible for me to help you.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, I am added example of my hash table. Shortly it works like this: each time $n/2$ different numbers (in range between 0 and $n$) are added to the table. When number is being added to the table, hash of that number is index in table. If the table already contains item under that index it being added to the list under the same index. 
On practice I am calculating mean as sum of lists lengths of the table divided by table length $m$. I am trying to find exact formula for calculating variance of lists lengths without generating test table.

Comment: The variance of the chain length should scale like $x^2$, since the length of each chain just gets multiplied by $x$. Yet this is not what you get. Perhaps you're not really calculating the variance? Please tell us what *exactly* you do, what *exact* formula you use. If $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ are the lengths of the chains (so $a_1 + \cdots + a_m = x(n/2)$), what are you calculating?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, to calculate variance I am saving list of chain lengths $a_1,\ldots,a_m$, than for each chain length calculating its probability $p$ by counting how many times it occurred in the saved list and dividing it by $m$. After calculating probability I am calculating $\sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i(a_i-mean)^2$. I am also tried to calculate variance by importing chain lengths to Excel and got same result

Comment: I don't understand what $p_i$ is. Each time you run your experiment (inserting $xn/2$ entries), you get lengths $a_1,\ldots,a_m$. Perhaps you run many experiments, and in the $t$'th experiment you get $a_1^t,\ldots,a_m^t$. Now you have all these numbers. What do you do with them?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, I am calculating like this: in first experiment I am adding $n/2$ one time and calculating variance. For second experiment I am creating new hash table and adding $n/2$ two times and calculating variance

Comment: What do you mean by “calculating variance”? What exactly are you calculating?